# Compare property of model in the list with the constant value

Tags: entity-framework, where-clause

Its a simple question but I am starting with EF and dont know:

I have two classes (db objects):

Company (simplified)

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }    
}
```

and userGroup (there are many users in the group):

```
public class UserGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

In controller I need to select the companies which have a specific UserGroupID. I dont know how to write the select condition. I mean something like:

```
        var currentUser = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var companies = db.Companies
            .Include(c => c.Address)
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .Where(c => c.UserGroups == currentUser.UserGroup)
            ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your `ApplicationUser` class, but I suppose it has a navigation property to `UserGroup`? If it does, you could do it like this:

```
db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId())
  .SelectMany(u => u.UserGroups)
  .SelectMany(g => g.Companies)
  .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks man. I needed to use select as you wrote. In my case: var companies = db.UserGroups.Where(g => g.ID == currentUser.UserGroup.ID)
                .SelectMany(g => g.Companies)
                .Distinct();

Answer (score 1):

I like to write the where clause over entity I want to return. In your case:

```
db.Companies.Where(c => c.UserGroups.Any(g => g.ID == currentUser.UserGroup.ID));
```

This way you don't have to add the Distinct().

Comment: Yes, this may be a more natural way for me too. Thanks Augusto.